# Patching a hole in wall for reuse

Tags: drywall, repair, concrete, brick, hole

I was trying to hang an IKEA Kallax shelf on the wall  but ended up tearing away part of the wall.  I am not too sure what kind of wall this is (*in a ~1960s apartment building*), first layer looks like drywall, no idea what the brownish layer is, but I know there's probably concrete/brick behind the brownish layer since I couldn't drill through it with a regular drill.

**What's the best way to patch it up so that I can try redoing it?**

Originally tried using some plastic anchors with screws for drywall, but the wall was too shallow and the screw + anchor couldn't go in very far (*clearly wasn't enough to hold the shelf as you can see*). I am thinking of trying to drill into the concrete/brick after patching the wall up and using some [sleeve anchors](http://Can%20anyone%20point%20me%20in%20the%20right%20direction%20as%20to%20what%20kind%20of%20screen%20I%20should%20get%20and%20where?) . The shelf weighs ~35lbs and I will be using 4 anchors to hold it up, so I would like the anchors to be able to hold up at least 50lbs in total.

The hole is about 4 in tall on white part and 2 in tall on brownish part, and 1 in at its deepest.

**Any tips on what type of anchor I should be using?**

[image: the hole in the wall]

Comment: May be stucco on brick or concrete. Use masonry drill bit and plastic wall plugs.

Comment: Is the brownish layer hard like concrete or softer liner compressed cardboard, possibly sawdust.

Comment: softer, so it's probably stucco like user263983 mentioned

Comment: There are many types of wedge/expansion anchor that you can choose from, but the important thing is to drill into the solid wall behind. It could be an old hollow plastering wall though.